# Finding the kth to last element of a singly linked list

Tags: java, recursion, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value, singly-linked-list

I have two recursive solutions to the "kth to last element of a singly linked list" problem in Java:

**Solution 1:**

```
public static Node nthToLast(Node head, int k , int i){
    if (head == null) return null;
    Node n = nthToLast(head.next, k, i);
    i = i + 1;

    if (i == k) return head;

    return n;
}
```

**Solution 2:**

```
public class IntWrapper {
    public int value = 0;
}
public static Node nthToLast(Node head, int k, IntWrapper i){
    if (head == null) return null;
    Node n = nthToLast(head.next, k, i);
    i.value = i.value + 1;

    if (i.value == k) return head;

    return n;
}
```

The first solution returns `null`, while the second solution works perfectly. The first solution passes `k` by value, while the second solution wraps the `int` value in a class and passes it.

I have two questions:

1. Why is the first solution not working in Java? Why is pass-by-value through the local variable `i` in each method call not working the same as the pass-by-reference version?
2. The `Integer` class in Java wraps `int`, but replacing the `int` to `Integer` in the first solution does not work as well. Why?

Comment: In your first solution i isn't initialized

Comment: @Vorsprung I believe "i" is a method argument, although I don't know what the initial invocation looks like.

Comment: The initial invocation looks like this: first solution:             Node n = nthToLast(testRootNode , 2 , 0);   second solution:            Node n = nthToLast(testRootNode , 2 , new IntWrapper());

Comment: Are you sure your solution gives you kth to last element, and not the kth from first element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Solution 2, you're using `IntWrapper` to remember values across recursive invocations. Here, `IntWrapper` acts like a global value.

If you use local variables such as a primitive integer, you cannot preserve the incremented (`i = i + 1`) values across invocations. Therefore, the statement `if (i == k) return head;` never becomes true, unless maybe if k = 1.

Most interestingly, you cannot use `Integer` because Java wrapper classes are immutable in nature. The moment you do `i = i + 1`, a new object is created (LHS) and the old one (RHS) is thrown away/garbage collected.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with being mutable/immutable, but rather with the semantics of `+` when applied to boxed types.

Comment: If IntWrapper "acts like a global value", would it be possible to just make IntWrapper a global variable instead? Is there any advantage/disadvantage to doing so?

Comment: Yes, you could have an IntWrapper instance that is global; in which case, you do not need to parameterize it. It is really easy to get your hands on global values from anywhere in the code - this ease translates to their biggest disadvantage: it is hard to reason about their state. As all things, it depends whether you choose to take it as a disadvantage. For example - a problem domain that is algorithmic in nature may not consider this as a disadvantage, whereas a business modelling OO solution might.

Answer (score 1):

1.
The first solution does not work because every time you pass the same value in a `i` variable. If you move the line `i = i + ​​1` over the line `Node n = nthToLast (head.next, k, i)`, everything should work without a problem.
2.
`Integer` class is immutable, so behaves like a normal `int`. That's why if you use an `Integer` in the first solution function will not work correctly. You can replace lines of code as I mentioned above that the first solution worked with an `Integer`.
The second solution works because the way you increment the counter does not overwrite the reference to the counting object.

Answer (score 0):

In your solution 1 you should increment i before calling recursively the method. This version should work:

```
public static Node nthToLast(Node head, int k , int i) {
    // checks empty case
    if (head == null) { return null; }

     // checks if current node is the solution
    if (i == k) { return head; }

    // else checks next node
    return nthToLast(head.next, k, i+1); 
}
```